# Merge associations always taking the value that satisfies a given test

Tags: associations, filtering, gathering

I have associations look like this:

```
data = {<|a -> {2, l1}, b -> {3, l1}|>, <|a -> {3, l2}, b -> {2, l2}|>}
```

I want the result:

```
<|a -> {3, l2}, b -> {3, l1}|>
```

The bigger digit of first value should be left.

Answer (score 4):

```
Merge[data, First @* MaximalBy[First]]
```

> ```
> <|a -> {3, l2}, b -> {3, l1}|>
> ```

Comment: I think too much about Union.